# Migrate users from foomla 1.5 to joomla 2.5

Tags: joomla, md5

in my joomla 1.5 password hash by md5+salt, they look like this:

> 6e3bb23b32702ee94ebc18e2a059fe4a:wxIZ6BNkAFpQk4ggeRvoOIrgbWerif0x

but on joomla 2.5 it is:

> $P$DTJoqPcMQgUhl6cPrzzBOTFIFHQaNf1

HOW can i change hash algorithm in joomla 2.5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

The older algorithm will works fine with 2.5 , only the length is changed

The New code is :

```
<?php

    jimport('joomla.user.helper');
    $password = "test";     
    JUserHelper::hashPassword($password);

?>
```

Older Version Code:

```
 jimport('joomla.user.helper');
 $salt = JUserHelper::genRandomPassword(32);
 $crypt = JUserHelper::getCryptedPassword($password_choose, $salt);
 $password = $crypt.':'.$salt;
```

When you are working with external php script load the Joomla  library to that file,

```
        define( '_JEXEC', 1 );
        define('JPATH_BASE', dirname(__FILE__) );//this is when we are in the root
        define( 'DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR );

        require_once( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'defines.php' );
        require_once( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'framework.php' );

        $mainframe =& JFactory::getApplication('site');
        $mainframe->initialise();
```

Hope it make sense..